# Nodejs on linux returning -1

Tags: node.js, linux, jersey-client

I'm using node.js (4.4.6) as RESTful service, and jersey-client (2.22.2) as client

The server and client are running on the same computer

When running it on windows everything works perfectly

When running it on Linux (Ubuntu) I receive status -1

Anyone knows what could be the problem?

Comment: Could you please provide some more information - any errors/logs? Does it start at all, or does it fail at a certain point while running?

Comment: No errors, everything is running, when I'm trying to send requests from postman or from a browser everything works perfect, only when using jersey-client it fails and only on Linux. By the way, when I'm using the same client on linux and directing it to the windows machine remotely it also works perfect